# Unable to get new unity particle system code working post update

Tags: unity-game-engine

I used to have the following particle system that worked.

```cs
// In the inspector I drag in the leaf particle system.
public ParticleSystem LeafStormParticleSystem;

private IEnumerator activate(float ActivateFor) {
    //Change number of particles to 150
    LeafStormParticleSystem.maxParticles = 150;

    //  LeafStormParticleSystem.
    var newEmission = LeafStormParticleSystem.emission;
    var rate = newEmission.rate; 
    rate.constantMin = 20;
    rate.constantMax = 21;
    newEmission.rate = rate;
```

Now as you can probably tell, this simple increases the number of particles. Now, this used to work and probably doesn't because of the new particle system I keep reading about.

However on this new particle system I have a question and issues getting it to work.

**Issue**

Correct me if i'm wrong but the particle system is defined as follows

```cs
void Start()
{
    ParticleSystem ps = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    var main = ps.main;

    main.startDelay = 5.0f;
    main.startLifetime = 2.0f;
}
```

Now if I have 3 particle systems, how do I specify which one i'm referring to? Since I cant define it as public and drag the particle system to it in the editor anymore?

**Issue B**

Now i tried following what unity said in their forums and did the following

```cs
ParticleSystem ps = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
var main = ps.main;

main.maxParticles = 150;
//  LeafStormParticleSystem.maxParticles = 150;

do not create your own module instances, get them from a ParticleSystem instance UnityEngine.ParticleSystem+MainModule.set_maxParticle
```

Any help with Issues A and B will be appreciated.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue A**

Only one ParticleSystem component can be attached to any one GameObject at a time. Sub-ParticleSystems must therefore be attached to separate GameObjects too (generally children of the GameObject holding the first ParticleSystem), which *can* be dropped directly onto public fields.

```
public ParticleSystem LeafStormParticleSystem;

void Start ()
{        
    if (LeafStormParticleSystem != null)
    {
        var main = LeafStormParticleSystem.main;
        main.maxParticles = 150;
    }
}
```

**Issue B**

Your code looks fine, however a critical part of the error message was missing; `NullReferenceException` which is telling you that a reference in your code is equal to `NULL`. In your case, that reference would be the `ps` variable used to store the ParticleSystem reference, which is either a consequence of not attaching this script to the GameObject holding your ParticleSystem or simply that you have no ParticleSystem attached at all. In either case, make sure both script and ParticleSystem are attached to the same GameObject and check your references like so;

```
void Start ()
{
    ParticleSystem ps = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();

    if (ps != null)
    {
        var main = ps.main;
        main.maxParticles = 150;
    }
}
```